# Show only current event and next event in fullcalendar.io in basicDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a Google Calendar with events that happen everyday. I'm using the fullcalendar.io framework to display my calendar embedded in a WordPress page. I am using the basicDay view of fullcalendar. What I want to do is only show the current event and maybe an event or two after from the Google calendar and to hide all of the events that happen before now. I'm not that great at Javascript so if anyone can give me some guidance on how I could get just the event happening NOW and maybe the next event to show, that would be great.

I was able to hide the older events with this code:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var minDate = moment();
            if (minDate >= event.end) {
                $(element).addClass('fc-state-disabled');
                return;
            }

            console.log(event);
        },
```

but I only want two events to show. The current event and the next event.

Thanks

Comment: use `$(element).addClass('fc-state-custom-hide')` && use css `.fc-state-custom-hide{ display:none;}`

Comment: @valarmorghulis how is this different than the `$(element).addClass('fc-state-disabled');` I already have in that code? I have a display:none in my css for .fc-state-disabled as well.

Comment: you shouldn't use the fullcalendar default classes bcoz you might not know what's the functionality behind that try using custom class as much as possible.

Comment: the .fc-state-disabled was working for hiding past events. .fc-state-custom-hide works too. i am hoping to hide future events that happen more than an hour away from the current event.